# I've been accidentally paid twice, what to do?

Tags: money, halal-haram

I am a freelancer working for overseas clients. I recently withdrew about $135 from this site. I got the money in my bank account, I spent it. Then, after two days, I got about the same amount of money (a few cents lost due to varying currency rate), and I gave it to charity as I thought the freelance site is a multinational company and there was no way for me to return the money.

And I am not even sure if they accidentally sent me twice or the mediating bank did, so I am not sure. Did I do the right thing?

Answer (score -3):

Assalamualaikum,

Every mistake that done by accident got AUTOMATICALLY forgiven by Allah,

EVERY SINGLE ONE,  EXCEPT "SHIRK" TO ALLAH

just istighfar and try your best to pay back even if U can only payback 1cent.

P.S.

The moment you post this, meaning you seek guidance and forgiveness, that already enough for Allah to forgive you.

Wallahualam.